# ARM assembly if(data & 0x01) rGPGDAT &= ~(0x1<<7);

Tags: assembly, arm, gpio

Now I'm study how to control ARM GPIO by assembly language.
so I'm trying to change C source to assembly language.

But I'm difficult with writing this part

```
if(data & 0x01) rGPGDAT &= ~(0x1<<7);

if(data & 0x02) rGPGDAT &= ~(0x1<<6);

if(data & 0x03) rGPGDAT &= ~(0x1<<5);

if(data & 0x04) rGPGDAT &= ~(0x1<<4);
```

I think that I should use TST. I don't know how to dealt with "if"

Comment: Yup, `tst` is indeed appropriate for a bitwise comparison. If you don't know how to implement conditional code in general, though, then it's probably worth studying an assembly tutorial first. Also, for relatively simple code sequences, looking at the disassembly of C code compiled at -O1 is usually quite informative (-O0 tends to emit so many redundant loads/stores/moves it's hard to see the wood for the trees).

Comment: Typically you would set some flags (tst is a good idea here) then branch over the false condition or branch to the true condition.  If full sized arm instructions (not thumb) conditional execution would be good here look at BIC.

Comment: are you sure your "if" are correct? `if (data & 0x01)`, `if (data & 0x02)` and `if (data & 0x04)` look like correct bit test to me, but `if (data & 0x03)` may be wrong ?! why are you trying to archive? Or is that just a typo?

Comment: in ARM you can often avoid branches by adding the condition directly to the opcode. andne e.g. only performs the and, if the zero flag is 0

Comment: @Tommylee2k Originally, It is 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to do this without branches:

```
mov r1, <your data>  ; change this accordingly
mov r2, <rGPGDAT>    ; change this accordingly
tst    r1,#1
andne  r2,#$FF -1
tst    r1,#2
andne  r2,#$FF -2
tst    r1,#4
andne  r2,#$FF -4
tst    r1,#8
andne  r2,#$FF -8
```

the key is the instruction and where you can define a contition for the instruction to be executed (in this case Z=0)
if the bit is set in r1, the `tst` clears the zero flag, and 
`andne` will clear the bit in r2

(not sure if you need andNE or andEQ here. also a loop would be more elegant but: i'm not at home atm, so I can't write propper code)

Comment: Thank your for your help. I think that I need study more about tst and insturctions set.

Comment: Tip: `bic` would be neater than `and` (this is precisely the job it exists for!); ne is indeed the right condition, as you're looking for the comparison result to be non-zero.